# error: 'class std::stack<>' has no member named 'pop_back'

Tags: c++

```
void MazeSolver::solveMaze()
{
    stack<Cell> myStack;
    Cell current = myVector.getAt(0, 0);
    myStack.push_back(current);
    int x, y;
    while (myStack.size() != 0)
    {
        current = myStack.pop_back();
        x = current.x_coord;
        y = current.y_coord;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following compile time error:

`/Users/snihalani/dev/c++rec/c++hw at  7:11PM`

`➜ main.cpp: In member function 'void hw1::MazeSolver::solveMaze()':`

`main.cpp:55:17: error: 'class std::stack<hw1::Cell>' has no member named 'push_back'`
`main.cpp:59:31: error: 'class std::stack<hw1::Cell>' has no member named 'pop_back'`

`[1]  + 18262 exit 1     g+ --std=c++11 main.cpp`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There's no question mark in this post.  For your reference: [std::stack has no member named 'pop_back'](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `push_back` to `push` and `pop_back` to `pop`. For more information, use [a good reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

Answer (score 4):

`std::stack<>` has a member function named `pop`, and another named `push`.  The stack can only do operations on the back, it is just `push` and `pop`.